# Wordpress Plugin and other pages not opening

Tags: plugins, permalinks, pages, wp-admin, dashboard

WordPress dashboard is open but the Plugin and other pages are not opening.
It's loading but not open. Below I attached the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What do you have in console? Look at there.

Comment: My dashboard is opening. But when I tried to access the plugins or page this loading image coming but not opening the plugin pages.

Comment: Yes I've understood it already. I said about the browser devtools. What is in the console tab or in the network tab.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.